# does a sum related to the prime factorization of the whole numbers.

Tags: limits, prime-factorization

to define this sum you need a function $f(x)$

$f(x)=$ the sum of the prime powers of $x$

$12=3^1\times2^2$ so
$f(12)=1+2$

$16=2^4$ so
$f(16)=4$

my question does this sum converge and if so what does it converge to?

$$\frac{f(2)}1+\frac{f(3)}2+\frac{f(4)}4+\frac{f(5)}8+\frac{f(6)}{16}+\cdots+\frac{f(x)}{2^{x-2}}+\cdots$$

Comment: Certainly $2^{f(x)} \le x$, so $f(x) / 2^x \le \log_2(x) / 2^x \le x / 2^x$, the sum of which converges by the ratio test. I couldn't tell you what to, though. Did you think of this problem yourself, or is it homework?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I thought of it myself I'm stuck at home waiting for my freshman year of high school. I've been thinking of problems to solve and ask

Comment: Haha, okay. The chances of a random sum like this having a nice closed form are often pretty slim. If you want practice evaluating series like this maybe it's better to find some exercises, but so long as you're doing maths, it's all great!

Comment: Although because this series converges at least geometrically, it converges pretty fast! It might be a fun idea to write a program that calculates the value of this series up to a certain number of terms (maybe even using a multiple-precision package to get lots of decimal places, or you could make your own)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it converges. You can estimate every $f(n)$ with $n$ itself, since $n \leq 2^n$ for every natural number. Then you have clearly convergence.

As to what it converges to, I don’t think it is possible to compute, and if it is I would be extremely surprised